# Extract Last word in sentence having desired prefix from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extract the last occurrence of a string starting with a desired prefix extracted(in this case mango) and put in a new column. What will be the fastest way to do this in python. I am providing a small example as follows

```
pd.DataFrame({"input_col": ["mango_1 apple_10 mango9 grape7","apple_10 mango8 grape7", "mango_1 mango2"],
              "desired_col": ["mango9","mango8","mango2"]
             }) 
                       input_col   desired_col
0  mango_1 apple_10 mango9 grape7  mango9
1          apple_10 mango8 grape7  mango8
2                  mango_1 mango2  mango2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because performance is important use list comprehension with `split`, filter by `startswith` and for last match value is used `reversed` with `next` statement (also is specify value if no match):

```
df['new'] = [next(reversed([i for i in x.split() if i.startswith('mango')]), 'no match') 
                           for x in df['input_col']]
print (df)
                        input_col desired_col     new
0  mango_1 apple_10 mango9 grape7      mango9  mango9
1          apple_10 mango8 grape7      mango8  mango8
2                  mango_1 mango2      mango2  mango2
```

Comment: This was the fastest. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can go with `str.findall` and use the string accessor again to index on the last match:

```
df['desired_col'] = df.input_col.str.findall(r'mango_*\d+').str[-1]

print(df)

             input_col              desired_col
0  mango_1 apple_10 mango9 grape7      mango9
1          apple_10 mango8 grape7      mango8
2                  mango_1 mango2      mango2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rfind` to locate the last occurrence of the prefix, get the substring that starts with the index `rfind` returns, and then choose the first item from the substring after splitting it with regard to `" "`.

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['input_col'][row['input_col'].rfind("mango"):].split(" ")[0], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
                        input_col desired_col  result
0  mango_1 apple_10 mango9 grape7      mango9  mango9
1          apple_10 mango8 grape7      mango8  mango8
2                  mango_1 mango2      mango2  mango2
```